how to fill with curvature face
I want to fill the bottom of an ear canal model with a curvature face like the picture
I try alt+ f, grid fill and f. But the fill face is too flat
What can I do to make the surface I fill in have a red line like trend in the graph, that is, the shape along the boundary
you can get my blend file from 


